# Visualizing Ten Node (Quadratic) Tetrahedron

Tags: graphics3d, tetgenlink

```
Needs["TetGenLink`"]
instTetgen = TetGenCreate[]; 
TetGenExpression[1]; 
pts = {{0., 0., 0.}, {2., 0., 0.}, {2., 0., 2.}, {0., 0., 2.}, {0., 
2., 0.}, {2., 2., 0.}, {2., 2., 2.}, {0., 2., 2.}}; 
TetGenSetPoints[instTetgen, pts]; 
instTetrahed = TetGenTetrahedralize[instTetgen, "-o2"]; 
elemPts = TetGenGetPoints[instTetrahed]; 
elemFaces = TetGenGetFaces[instTetrahed]; 
meshElements = TetGenGetElements[instTetrahed]; 
nElements = Length[meshElements]; 
nVertex = Length[elemPts]; 
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.5], GraphicsComplex[elemPts, Polygon[elemFaces]]}, Boxed -> False]; 

elemPts
{{0.,0.,0.},{2.,0.,0.},{2.,0.,2.},{0.,0.,2.},{0.,2.,0.},{2.,2.,0.},{2.,2.,2.},{0.,2.,2.},{2.,2.,1.},{1.,1.,0.},{1.,1.,1.},{1.,2.,1.},{1.,2.,0.},{0.,1.,0.},{0.,1.,1.},{1.,0.,1.},{1.,1.,2.},{0.,1.,2.},{0.,0.,1.},{1.,0.,2.},{2.,1.,2.},{1.,0.,0.},{2.,1.,1.},{2.,0.,1.},{2.,1.,0.},{1.,2.,2.},{0.,2.,1.}}
elemFaces
{{7,6,1},{7,5,6},{6,5,1},{1,5,7},{8,1,3},{8,4,1},{1,4,3},{3,4,8},{1,7,3},{1,2,7},{7,2,3},{3,2,1},{6,2,7},{1,2,6},{7,8,1},{3,8,7},{1,5,8},{8,5,7}}
meshElements
{{7,6,1,5,9,10,11,12,13,14},{8,1,3,4,15,16,17,18,19,20},{1,7,3,2,11,21,16,22,23,24},{6,7,1,2,9,11,10,25,23,22},{7,1,3,8,11,16,21,26,15,17},{1,8,7,5,15,26,11,14,27,12}}
(*Ten nodes of the first tetrahedral element are:*)
elemPts[[meshElements[[1]]]]
{{2.,2.,2.},{2.,2.,0.},{0.,0.,0.},{0.,2.,0.},{2.,2.,1.},{1.,1.,0.},{1.,1.,1.},{1.,2.,1.},{1.,2.,0.},{0.,1.,0.}}
```

Is there a way to visualize the polyhedron such that all the ten nodes of the tetrahedral elements are considered and not only the primary four nodes of each tetrahedral element?

Comment: Can you explain which are the ten nodes?

Comment: @Szabolcs In the above example, there are six tetrahedral elements in the cube. Each of these tetrahedral elements will have ten nodes. The first four nodes are the same as in the case of linear tetrahedral elements, the rest six are midpoints of each of the edges.             meshElements[[1]] contains {7,6,1,5,9,10,11,12,13,14} these ten points.

Comment: @Szabolcs I have edited the question and provided the ten nodes of the first tetrahedral element.

Answer (score 1):

here is one element:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], GraphicsComplex[ elemPts , { 
      Polygon[#[[{1, 2, 3}]]],
      Polygon[#[[{1, 4, 3}]]],
      Polygon[#[[{1, 2, 4}]]],
      Polygon[#[[{2, 3, 4}]]],
      {Red, Opacity[1], PointSize[.02],Point[#]}
      }]}, Boxed -> False] &@ meshElements[[1]]
```

[image]

and all:

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[.5], GraphicsComplex[ elemPts , { 
       Polygon[#[[{1, 2, 3}]]],
        Polygon[#[[{1, 4, 3}]]] ,
       Polygon[#[[{1, 2, 4}]]],
       Polygon[#[[{2, 3, 4}]]] , {Red, Opacity[1], PointSize[.02], 
        Point[#]}
       }]}, Boxed -> False] & /@ meshElements]
```

[image]

note that *your* graphic is not composed to tetrahedrons, in fact all of the rendered polygons are on the faces of the cube. I'm not sure whats wrong though.  The `elemPts` list has a point at the center of the cube `{1,1,1}`, yet in your figure there is no vertex or edge through that point.

Comment: Thanks. I think it is because I just used the faces which are at the boundary. If I used the -f flag also along with -o2 while using the TetGenTetrahedralize command. It will consider that point as well.

Comment: i see. if you didnt use opacity it would look  ok. Maybe the docs for `TetGenGetFaces` could say it just gives external faces.

Comment: Your suggestion takes care of the points but the tetrahedral faces do not change accordingly. Example if i change elemPts[[9]] = {2,2,1} to {2,2,3}, The point goes out of the cube but the cube does not change its shape. I am doing the dynamics where the vertex points evolve with time,  I want to visualize the shape changes in the polygon as the values of the vertex point changes.

Comment: If you move the edge nodes away from the mid-point of the tet edges the resulting object is no longer a tetrahedron, the faces no longer polyhedron. The edges become quadratic.  At the very least this should be a new question.  (BTW in my experience commercial FEM packages punt on the issue and treat second order tets as first order for redering purpose.)